# git: show the future of a file from an old commit

Tags: git

I am looking at a particular old commit in a complex repo with loads of commits, I see a file in the commit that isn't in the current HEAD of master.

I want to know what happened to that file? Did it get deleted or moved? Were there edits to the file since that commit?

`git blame` seems to solve the opposite problem. I want `git unblame` I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git log -- example.txt` will list all commits which touched that path, including the commit which renamed or removed the file.

Comment: Huh. I'm not sure why I thought this but I figured that would only work if the file was there in the checked out commit. Makes me wonder what would happen if you moved the file and then put something else in that location at a later time. Thanks though! :)

Comment: Oh wow the thing I'm looking for has moved so many times. Even so git log is probably the easiest way, though tedious.

Comment: `git log --follow` may help you trace the history of a file that's been moved around.

Comment: `--follow` isn't working for me in this case but maybe the move wasn't done in a way that preserved tracking. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

`gitk filename` also helped me successfully investigate the lifecycle of a file tracked in git

Comment: I had to run `gitk -- filename` as the file is not in the current commit. Still doesn't doesn't help navigate multiple moves either. Thanks though. :)